# Integrate OneDrive into Windows 7 explorer sidebar

Tags: windows-7, onedrive

In Windows 8.1, OneDrive is integrated within Explorer's sidebar:
[image: Windows 8.1 OneDrive]

However, on Windows 7, the best that I could do is to show OneDrive as a Link (inside favorites):
[image: Windows 7 OneDrive]

My question is: there are any way that I can make OneDrive appear as a "special" group in Windows 7? Or this is more related to the fact that Windows 8.1 has it deeply integrated with the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subst` to map it on a disk volume.

Assuming your OneDrive folder is under *`C:\Users\<USERNAME>\OneDrive`* you can map it on drive **`N:\`** by writing on command prompt:

```
subst N: C:\Users\<USERNAME>\OneDrive
```

Change `<USERNAME>` with your windows account's username

You can find the exact path to your OneDrive by **right clicking on OneDrive** -> select **properties**

Answer (score 1):

The best I was able to do is adding OneDrive as a network location.

Just open Explorer, in address bar type `Network Shortcuts` or `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts` and then create in opened location shortcut to your OneDrive Folder (Right click on free space -> New -> Shortcut).

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRAIn.png) [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyCXQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do by changing the navigation pane options.

[image]

Another way would be to create a new Library and add the OneDrive folder to it. It would then show up in the list of Libraries in your current navigation pane.